# Adding "=" on ajax request body

Tags: ajax, superagent

I'm trying to send an ajax request but when i send the variable "newValue" which is a String the server alwasy gets the content plus a "=". So if i send "20.09.2009" the server gets "20.09.2009=". Why?
I cant get rid of this. Below is my code:
Do i have to send specific headers?

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: newValue,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.perrorCode){//there is a validation error
                this.setState({error: `Validation Error. Expected format: ${data.perrorMessage}. Got format: ${data.pvalue}`});
                callback(false);
            } else
                callback(true);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
```

If i print out the value right before, there is no "=".
If I use advanced Rest Client addon for google chrome and set the exact same thing, the server responds correctly as he gets only "20.09.2009"

Comment: How are you testing what the server gets? Have you looked at the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see if it is added before the data is sent? How are you reading it on the server? If you are sending plain text why are you setting the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` instead of leaving at the default?

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my question.
I've removed "dataType: 'json'" but I still get the error

Comment: *I've removed "dataType: 'json'"* — why?

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAO0Lw6jywRO-5FrkIyATtDslMPsrMkXlyQ — I can't reproduce the problem. (Still suspect it is a combination of your server side code and the way you haven't fixed the Content-Type).

Comment: because i dont pass a json, i just pass a string

Comment: to what should I set the content type?

Comment: `dataType` sets the Accept header, not the Content-Type header. What you send to the server is irrelevant as data as `dataType` is concerned.

Comment: The content-type should be `text/plain` as I said in my original comment.

Comment: oh so i was a bit confused about contenttype and datatype. 
Adding contentType solved my problem, thank you!
could you please create an answer so i can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) suggested, I've added the attribute `contentType: 'text/plain'` and my problem was gone.